# C# ASP NET MVC 5.0 Postback goes to Html.RenderPartial() on View Model Validation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, model-validation, html.beginform, html.renderpartial

I have an unexpected post back to a Html.RenderPartial() action when the main page fails model data validation.  If there are no errors with model validation the page posts back to the expected controller action.  Has anyone run into this and what solution did they use?

Further explanation:

I have a MVC .cshtml view which has a post back setup as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Profile", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // html code and stuff..

    @{ Html.RenderAction("ImageUpload", "User"); }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

When I click the "Save" button the page should post back to `User/Profile` as setup in the `Html.BeginForm` method: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Profile", "User", FormMethod.Post))`.

The page works as expected when I do a post back and model validation has no errors...it posts to `User/Profile` as expected.

However, when there is a validation error with the main view model the page posts back to the `Html.RederPartial` action: `@{ Html.RenderAction("ImageUpload", "User"); }`.  In other words, instead of posting to `User/Profile` as expected it posts to `User/ImageUpload`.

SNAPSHOT OF VIEWMODEL (model provided to User/Profile)

```
[Required]
[StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 20)]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "About Me* (Write up to 1000 characters about yourself)")]
public virtual string Summary { get; set; }

public ActionResult Profile(UserModel userModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //DO STUFF
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(userModel);
}
```

Where the user does not meet the model validation by entering less than 20 characters in the `Summary` property (the min length validation parameter) the post back goes to the `Html.RenderPartial()` rather than the expected `Html.BeginForm("Profile", "User", FormMethod.Post)`.

Has anyone run into this before and any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Show the code in the `Profile()` POST method. And what is the view returned by the `ImageUpload()` method? Does that happen to contain a `<form>` element? And why are you not including client side validation to prevent the form being submitted?

Comment: I've added the code in Profile() although the point is Profile() is never getting called when the error occurs.  ImageUpload() does indeed include a form element but as a RenderPartial() this is fine.  Client side validation has issues with certain jquery widget controls which stop it from working.